# Указатель на метод класса и скобки

Tags: c++, ооп

Чем обусловлена невозможность писать указатель на метод в скобках?
Почему запись указателя на метод должна быть именно

```
 ClassName::*MethodName
```

Почему нельзя так?

```
 ClassName::(*MethodName)
```

Если это какая-то особенность синтаксиса, прошу дать развёрнутый ответ, т.к. тема очень уж интересная

Comment: Развернутый???? Что тут разворачивать? чтобы вы вот такое случайное не написали **ClassName(*MethodName)** что будет вполне валидным кодом, только делающим совсем не тоже самое что ClassName::*MethodName

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков Синтаксис такой действительно по этой причине?

Comment: Давайте зайдем с вами с другой стороны, что по вашему должно значить запись вот такого вида? **ClassName::(*MethodName)**? Просто вот такая запись ClassName(*MethodName) это класс по ссылке =)

Comment: @Владимир , исходя из вопроса я предполагал, что "оборачивание" в скобки не изменит смыл выражения, что разнилось с практическим применением. Я только так могу ответить на вопрос " что по вашему должно значить запись вот такого вида? ClassName::(*MethodName)?".

Comment: @Владимир , благодарю за пояснение :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Не очень понимаю, на какой ответ вы расчитываете. Почему? Потому что в стандарте так написано. Должно быть, это сделано, чтобы не усложнять грамматику понапрасну.

Открываем грамматику для member pointers:

> #### [[dcl.mptr]/1](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.mptr#1)
>
> ...
>
> *nested-name-specifier* `*` *attribute-specifier-seq<sub>opt</sub>* *cv-qualifier-seq<sub>opt</sub>* D1
>
> and the *nested-name-specifier* denotes a class ...

Выражаясь простым языком,

- *nested-name-specifier* - это `класс::` (именно в этом случае; в общем случае у него [более широкое значение](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.prim.id.qual#nt:nested-name-specifier)),
- `*` - это `*`.
- *attribute-specifier-seq<sub>opt</sub>* - это опциональный набор атрибутов вида `[[...]]`,
- *cv-qualifier-seq<sub>opt</sub>* - это опциональные `const` и/или `volatile`.
- `D1` - оставшаяся часть объявления, в вашем случае просто имя переменной.

Тут нигде не написано, что после *nested-name-specifier* может быть `(`.